# Rails prevent url from being changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I'm trying to figure out a way to prevent someone from changing parts of the url. I've setup my website so that no one can sign up or create a account so anyone visiting is a guest.

For example, I've set the url in this part of the website to look for the value of `1a` from `/pathfinder/a/quest1/1a/q1sub1/` in order to display a certain part of the index page of `q1sub1`.

If someone were to change the value of `1a` to `1n` I would like to test if the url has changed and give some sort of error message.

Not sure what code excerpts to share in this case so let me know if you need more info.

I'm open to any ideas and appreciate any input. Thank you!

Comment: This goes against the design of HTTP.

Comment: It's something that you can't control. It's coming to your server and you get it as it is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it is a problem when the user changes the URL form `1a` to `1n` and queries another range of data? What problem exactly do you try to solve? What would happen if you do allow these requests to go through?

Comment: I'm making a choose your own adventure webpage and part of this includes having them choose a certain path. In this case if they enter **1** in a form under the quest1#index page that entry of **1** would be rewritten as **1a** and tacked on the url for the q1sub1#index page as **1a/q1sub1** and this would allow a certain part of the story could be shown to the user. If they choose **2** the url would **1b/q1sub1** along with a different narrative. What I'm trying to prevent someone from changing the **1a** or **1b** to something not useable that completely throws the story off

Answer (score 0):

The, URL by design, can't be controlled by your application.  But if you want to track where the user was previously, in all controller you have have access to `request.referrer` which should tell you where the request came from.  You might add some conditional logic to your controller and redirect the user if the `request.referrer` is something you want to restrict.  So in your controller action something like this:

```
def show # for example
  if request.referrer != "http://example.com/myformpage"
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Invalid access"
  else 
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

However this is still not secure as headers can be spoofed (thanks to @Holgar Just).  If you really want security in your application you should read the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)  and if you need more granular control over users permissions, maybe checkout [CanCanCan gem](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)

Comment: Note that the Referer header too can be arbitrarily spoofed by some clients (or remain entirely absent). You should not rely on it for security reasons. In fact, anything sent by the client can not be relied on in any way to be consistent, correct or even present without strict checks.

Comment: @HolgerJust good point, which I alluded to, but I've updated my answer thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do what you describe is to fingerprint the URLs before sending them to your client, using a hash function that includes a secret [pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_(cryptography)). The idea is that if the client tampers with and URL the fingerprint won't match anymore, and since the fingerprint is generated with a server-side secret, the client won't be able to generate a new one that matches the new URL.

Here is an example.

The user will access `/foo` and pass a custom `data` parameter. The application will use this param to build a customized URL with format  `/my/secret/:one/path/:two`, and redirect the client to it. This is just to keep things simple, and the same approach could be applied if the generated URL were to be used as a `<a href="...">` in a page.

The generated URL contains a fingerprint, and if the client tampers with either the URL or the fingerprint, or if the fingerprint is missing, the application will respond with a 403.

Let's look at the code. The routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get :foo, to: 'example#foo'
  get '/my/secret/:one/path/:two', to: 'example#bar', as: 'bar'
end
```

And the controller:

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
  # GET   /foo?data=xx  foo_path
  #
  def foo
    user_data = request[:data]
    go_to_path = bar_path(one: user_data, two: "foobar")
    go_to_path += "?check=#{url_fingerprint(go_to_path)}"

    redirect_to go_to_path
  end

  # GET   /my/secret/:one/path/:two  bar_path
  #
  def bar
    unless valid_request?
      render plain: "invalid request!", status: 403
      return
    end

    render plain: "this is a good request", status: 200
  end

  private

  SECRET = ENV.fetch("URL_FINGERPRINT_SECRET", "default secret")

  # Calculate the fingerprint of a URL path to detect
  # manual tampering.
  #
  # If you want to restrict this to a single client, add
  # some unique identifier stored in a cookie.
  #
  def url_fingerprint(path)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(path + SECRET)
  end

  def valid_request?
    return false unless params[:check].present?
    params[:check] == url_fingerprint(request.path)
  end
end
```

With this, the client would start with:

```
$ curl -i -s http://localhost:3000/foo?data=hello | grep Location
Location: http://localhost:3000/my/secret/hello/path/foobar?check=da343dd84accb4c0f5f7ff1d6e68152ac124ca1a39ce4746623bcb7b9043cab3
```

And then:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/my/secret/hello/path/foobar?check=da343dd84accb4c0f5f7ff1d6e68152ac124ca1a39ce4746623bcb7b9043cab3
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

this is a good request
```

But if the URL gets modified:

```
curl -i http://localhost:3000/my/secret/IWASCHANGED/path/foobar?check=da343dd84accb4c0f5f7ff1d6e68152ac124ca1a39ce4746623bcb7b9043cab3
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

invalid request!
```

The same would happen if the fingerprint itself was modifed or if it was missing.